# WordPress Parenting Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, parent-child

I have the following

```
GrandParent
-Parent01
--Child
-Parent02
--Child
--Child
-Parent03
--Child
```

I wish to find a solution that when Im on the Grandparent page, that it will only return the parents and not the children IE.

```
GrandParent
-Parent01
-Parent02
-Parent03
```

This is the code I have at present, and it produces all parents and children of the grandparent page, and places them into a table.

```
<?php $postid = get_the_ID(); ?> 
<?php /* $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' =>$postid)); */
$pages = get_children(array(
 'numberposts' =>30,
'post_parent' => $heading_page->post_id
 ));
$tCount= 0;
?> 
<table align="center" width="100%"><tr>
<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>
<?php     if($tCount % 2 == 0) 
{
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}?>
<td>  
<div id="polaroid">  
<figure>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(300,250)); ?></a>
    <figcaption>   
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($page->ID); ?>"><?php echo $page-   >post_title ?>
</a></figcaption>
</figure>
</div>  
 </td> 
<?php $tCount++; endforeach; ?>
</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$heading_page->post_id` and `$postid = the_post_ID();` are the same value you can just check the `post_parent` attribute in the loop and `continue` when they don't match:

```
<?php foreach ( $pages as $page ): ?>
<?php if ( $postid != $page->post_parent ) continue; ?>
```